# Quagga not propagating prefix to other eBGP neighbour

Tags: bgp, quagga

I am trying to get Quagga do something as simple as advertising a eBGP learned prefix to another eBGP connected neighbour. Simple enough right?

BGPd config snippet

```
!
router bgp 64620
 bgp router-id 172.29.253.80
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 172.29.253.80/32
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 10.35.253.2 remote-as 64901
 neighbor 10.35.253.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.35.253.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor 10.47.0.254 remote-as 64621
 neighbor 10.47.0.254 ebgp-multihop 255
 neighbor 10.47.0.254 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.47.0.254 soft-reconfiguration inbound
!
```

Prefix 10.47.0.0/16 learned from neighbour 10.47.0.254 and re-advertised to 10.35.253.2

```
# sh ip bgp 10.47.0.0/16
BGP routing table entry for 10.47.0.0/16
Paths: (1 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
  Advertised to non peer-group peers:
  10.35.253.2
  64621
    10.47.0.254 from 10.47.0.254 (10.47.0.254)
      Origin IGP, localpref 100, valid, external, best
      Last update: Mon Mar 19 08:35:28 2018
```

But checking the advertised-routes to 10.35.253.2 reveals it (10.47.0.0/16) is indeed not advertised. I also verified this with tcpdump.

```
# sh ip bgp neighbors 10.35.253.2 advertised-routes 
BGP table version is 0, local router ID is 172.29.253.80
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
              i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 172.29.253.80/32 10.35.253.1              0         32768 i

Total number of prefixes 1
```

BGPd version

```
# /usr/lib/quagga/bgpd --version
bgpd version 0.99.24.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in Quagga; 
[https://bugzilla.quagga.net/show_bug.cgi?id=972](https://bugzilla.quagga.net/show_bug.cgi?id=972%20https://bugzilla.quagga.net/show_bug.cgi?id=972)

Solved by switching to FRR which seems to be more actively maintained.